# REGEXP("CORA:.*")

Tags: uima, ruta

I had a doubt in this rule Line{-REGEXP("CORA:.*") -> MARK(Reference)}; What CORA:.*means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `CORA:.*` is interpreted as a regular expression. It is directly delegated to the Pattern implementation of Java. It means that the text the regular expression is applied on needs to start with the string `CORA:` followed by arbitrary characters (`.*`). The conditions checking the regular expression is negated, thus the rule creates annotations of the type Reference for each visible Line annoation that starts not with the string `CORA:`.

I assume in the context of the rule, the document starts with a line `CORA:` which indicates the layout/structure/source of the references.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*